# A Java Do/While loop that skips the While condition

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while

I am having trouble with the 
Do/While loop I am using. No matter what character or string that the user types in, the if block is shown, even when the while condition is not met.

More specifically, this code is *meant* to give the conditional (Do you want to calculate a score?) and based on the user response, continue with the if block (user = y ---> What is your name etc) or, when the which statement is not met, skip it (User = n ----> Program ends).

The code I used is below:

Please bear in mind that this code is not finished and some variables that are shown are not used yet.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main (String [] args) {





        //Declares letters to allow repetition of program
        final String START= "y";

        //Declerations of variables

        //Declares space for user's name
        String Name;

        //Declares space for user's year of birth
        int Year;

        //Declares space for user's double value, day and month of birth entered
        //by user
        double birthDM;

        //Declares space for int value day of birth, calculated from double value
        int day;

        //Declares space for int value month of birth, calculated from double value
        int month;

        //Declares space for int of calculated score
        int Score = 0;

        //Declares space for the string value of test (check wording)
        String confirmation;

        //Declares space for total number of scores calculated
        int Total;

        //Initilisaton of Scanner object
        Scanner sc;

        //Declares the space for the string that will carry the initilising letter 
        String userStart;

        //Declares space for the char that will activate program
        char yesChar;

        // Program Start



        //User input to begin loop or not (test)
        System.out.println(
                "The following program will calculate an score from your name and birthday.");
        System.out.println(" ");

        do {
            System.out.println("Would you like to calculate and score?");
            sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            userStart=sc.next();
            if (uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART));
            {
                System.out.println("What is your name?");
                userName=sc.next();
                System.out.println("What is the year of your birth?");
                birthYear = sc.nextInt();
            }
        } while(!uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART));

        System.out.println("Program End");
    }
}
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put your `while` condition at the start of the loop, not the end...

Comment: What is this supposed to mean: `final int SPRING = 9 | 10 | 11;`?

Comment: The numbers stood for the three months of spring in the southern hemisphere (September, October and November). Howvever, this is now changed in the new code I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon here:

```
if (uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART));
```

That will fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `;` from  `if (uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART))`

Like this :

```
if (uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART))
{
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    userName=sc.next();

    System.out.println("What is the year of your birth?");
    birthYear = sc.nextInt();
}
else
    System.exit(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have given a `;` after `if` like this
`if(....);` that means `;` is a null statement.

It makes the `{ ... }` after `if` a *block*.

So after checking condition nothing happens.

- if it is true the null statement is executed `;` and program goes to the block.
- If it is false there is no `else` so again, the program goes to block.

You will have to ***remove*** the `;`.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. I removed the ; and it worked well. :)

Comment: By the way, you should accept an answer that you think is the most accurate for you :) and get some reputation points in return ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the `if` thingy from the `while` instead of checking the same condition twice - and remove the extra `;` after the while, if etc.

```
do {
    System.out.println("Would you like to calculate and Ess-score?");
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    uProgStart=sc.next();
} while(!uProgStart.equalsIgnoreCase(PROGSTART))

System.out.println("What is your name?");
userName=sc.next();
System.out.println("What is the year of your birth?");
birthYear = sc.nextInt();
```